# How do I add permissions to group to match user permissions?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Some one messed up /usr/local/ permissions, so that nobody else can access it. Now I would like to duplicate user permissions to group permissions, since chmod g+rx -R /usr/local is unsafe. How should this be done?

Using linux (ubuntu 10.04).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can copy permissions:

```
chmod -R g=u /usr/local
```

This will copy the user permissions to the group permissions.

Comment: Elegant, Dennis; I did not know that!

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /usr/local
chmod -R g-rwx .
find . -perm -u+r -exec chmod g+r {} \;
find . -perm -u+w -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find . -perm -u+x -exec chmod g+x {} \;
```

This first clears the group permissions from all files.  Then it should search down, examining each file for each of the three user permission bits in turn (r, w, x).  For each permission, when it finds a file that has that bit set (disregarding their other user permission bits), it sets the equivalent group bit on for that file.

I **strongly** advise you to test this on a random subdirectory first, preferably with some corner-case files in it that you make yourself.  But it works in my comparable tests.

Comment: This is what I was just testing before posting.

Comment: <grin> sorry, iain!

Comment: That would be definitely slow for large amount of files since each file would be parsed three times.

Comment: I completely agree.  Dennis' solution is way superior; but if it hadn't been known, or existed, mine was still faster than doing it by hand!

Answer (score 0):

i did find this perl based solution on the net also.

```
find . | perl -ne 'chomp; $a = (stat $_)[2] & 07777; $a = ($a & 07707) | (($a >> 3) & 070); chmod($a, $_)'
```

but the

```
    chmod g=u
```

mentioned elsewhere is better i think