# awscli v2 needs sudo to run otherwise get permission denied error ubuntu 20.04.01

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, aws-cli

I've installed the awscli V2 as per the official AWS instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-install):

```
$ curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
$ unzip awscliv2.zip
$ sudo ./aws/install
```

The installation seems to work OK, except that I cannot use the aws command without sudo.

```
$ sudo aws --version
$ aws-cli/2.0.50 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.4.0-47-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20
```

Without sudo...

```
$ aws --version

Command 'aws' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo snap install aws-cli  # version 1.15.58, or
sudo apt  install awscli   # version 1.18.69-1ubuntu0.20.04.1

See 'snap info aws-cli' for additional versions.
```

Further details:

```
$ which aws # displays nothing
$ sudo which aws
/usr/local/bin/aws
$ /usr/local/bin/aws
bash: /usr/local/bin/aws: Permission denied
```

If I start to look at where the links are going they get very convoluted:

```
$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Sep 21 16:43 /usr/local/bin/aws -> /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws

$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Sep 21 16:43 /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws -> ../dist/aws

$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/2.0.50/dist
total 48400
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root   214121 Sep 21 16:43 array.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root   237647 Sep 21 16:43 _asyncio.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  4136160 Sep 21 16:43 aws
drwxr-x--- 6 root root     4096 Sep 21 16:43 awscli
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root  4151368 Sep 21 16:43 aws_completer
.
.
.
```

In the final directory it appears that the execute bit has been dropped and this might be the problem, but this seems so fundamental an issue yet I can't find any other reports of this problem.

Can anyone tell me what is going on? Thank.

Adding o+x to the aws file in the last directory doesn't fix the problem.
If I try installing via apt that seems to work OK, but I get the V1 API which I don't want.

Comment: It is truly mind boggling that Amazon would make such a large mistake in packaging their software. Learning permissions is one of the first things Linux admins and developers need to do.

Comment: Why not just do `sudo apt install awscli` ?  failing that `pip install awscli`

Comment: @Timothyc using apt gives the V1 CLI, as that is the repo version. I could use pip, but I always prefer following the vendor's documented instructions where possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What worked for me was giving permission recursively to aws-cli folder

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/aws-cli
```

Comment: That nailed it, works for Centos/8 too.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be:

```
chmod -R o=g /usr/local/aws-cli
```

This will keep all of the file/directory permission restrictive for root, but allow all on the system to use the group permissions.

More information here [Copy a file's owner permissions to group permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/284428/copy-a-files-owner-permissions-to-group-permissions)

Comment: cool, I didn't know it is possible to copy permission from other categories like that ! Thanks